# django multiple choices with yes no options

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Consider this as the model

**test = Industry.objects.all()**

and the result is

```
[<Industry: test 1>, <Industry: test 2>, <Industry: test 3>]
```

My model field is

```
options = models.ManyToManyField(Industry, default='')
```

And in my forms.py

```
options = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'contract-text-fld'}), queryset=Industry.objects.all(), required=False)
```

As all know the outpu form looks like

```
checkbox1
checkbox1
checkbox1
```

But I need something like this

```
label1      Yes(radio)     No(radio)
label2      Yes(radio)     No(radio)
label3      Yes(radio)     No(radio)
```

Is it possible if yes how can I handle this?

Comment: The short answer is that there's not a built-in representation for an M2M field as a Radio choice in Django. You will most likely have to write your own widget to allow the user to select the objects in the relationship. Writing custom widgets isn't all that difficult. This is a bit older post, but gives a good overview: http://tothinkornottothink.com/post/10815277049/django-forms-i-custom-fields-and-widgets-in-detail

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard widget to display the `ManyToManyField` in a way you would like. You will need to write a custom widget to do this.

Base widget documentation will be useful:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/

A tutorial on how to write a custom widget: http://tothinkornottothink.com/post/10815277049/django-forms-i-custom-fields-and-widgets-in-detail